# План выполнения запроса PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица разбитая партицированием по диапазонам значений. Грубо говоря, таблица разбита сначала по номерам приборов, а каждый номер прибора разбит по месяцам. Делаю, например, такой запрос:

```
SELECT t1.quat, t2.quat
 FROM offofent.orient as t1 
INNER JOIN offofent.orient as t2 ON 
t1.datetime = t2.datetime 
WHERE t1.datetime 
BETWEEN '2017-04-04 00:00:00' AND '2017-04-05 00:00:00' 
AND t2.datetime 
BETWEEN '2017-04-04 00:00:00' AND '2017-04-05 00:00:00' 
AND t1.pr_num = 6 AND t2.pr_num = 7;
```

Т.е запрашиваю некие данные по двум номерам приборов за день.
При таком запросе план такой:

```
"Hash Join  (cost=74686.63..189117.42 rows=469911 width=106)"
"  Hash Cond: (t2.datetime = t1.datetime)"
"  ->  Append  (cost=0.00..97983.76 rows=263257 width=61)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on orient t2  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=40)"
"              Filter: ((datetime >= '2017-04-04 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (datetime <= '2017-04-05 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (pr_num = 7))"
"        ->  Seq Scan on orient_7 t2_1  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=40)"
"              Filter: ((datetime >= '2017-04-04 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (datetime <= '2017-04-05 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (pr_num = 7))"
"        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on orient_0417_7 t2_2  (cost=6186.79..97983.76 rows=263255 width=61)"
"              Recheck Cond: ((datetime >= '2017-04-04 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (datetime <= '2017-04-05 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
"              Filter: (pr_num = 7)"
"              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on orient_0417_7_pkey  (cost=0.00..6120.98 rows=263255 width=0)"
"                    Index Cond: ((datetime >= '2017-04-04 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (datetime <= '2017-04-05 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
"  ->  Hash  (cost=70762.44..70762.44 rows=168815 width=61)"
"        ->  Append  (cost=0.00..70762.44 rows=168815 width=61)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on orient t1  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=40)"
"                    Filter: ((datetime >= '2017-04-04 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (datetime <= '2017-04-05 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (pr_num = 6))"
"              ->  Seq Scan on orient_6 t1_1  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=40)"
"                    Filter: ((datetime >= '2017-04-04 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (datetime <= '2017-04-05 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (pr_num = 6))"
"              ->  Index Scan using orient_0417_6_pkey on orient_0417_6 t1_2  (cost=0.43..70762.44 rows=168813 width=61)"
"                    Index Cond: ((datetime >= '2017-04-04 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (datetime <= '2017-04-05 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
"                    Filter: (pr_num = 6)"
```

Т.е он сразу переходит к нужным партициям, и сканирует их по индексу.

Если же задать без указания интервала дат по второму прибору:

```
SELECT t1.quat, t2.quat
 FROM offofent.orient as t1 
INNER JOIN offofent.orient as t2 ON 
t1.datetime = t2.datetime 
WHERE t1.datetime 
BETWEEN '2017-04-04 00:00:00' AND '2017-04-05 00:00:00'  
AND t1.pr_num = 6 AND t2.pr_num = 7;



"Hash Join  (cost=74686.63..992945.34 rows=664090 width=106)"
"  Hash Cond: (t2.datetime = t1.datetime)"
"  ->  Append  (cost=0.00..434616.47 rows=12592944 width=61)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on orient t2  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=40)"
"              Filter: (pr_num = 7)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on orient_7 t2_1  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=40)"
"              Filter: (pr_num = 7)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on orient_0117_7 t2_2  (cost=0.00..17.13 rows=3 width=40)"
"              Filter: (pr_num = 7)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on orient_0217_7 t2_3  (cost=0.00..17.13 rows=3 width=40)"
"              Filter: (pr_num = 7)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on orient_0317_7 t2_4  (cost=0.00..44399.40 rows=1354752 width=61)"
"              Filter: (pr_num = 7)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on orient_0417_7 t2_5  (cost=0.00..136310.81 rows=3929665 width=61)"
"              Filter: (pr_num = 7)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on orient_0517_7 t2_6  (cost=0.00..239921.36 rows=6909709 width=61)"
"              Filter: (pr_num = 7)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on orient_0617_7 t2_7  (cost=0.00..13847.90 rows=398792 width=61)"
"              Filter: (pr_num = 7)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on orient_0717_7 t2_8  (cost=0.00..17.13 rows=3 width=40)"
"              Filter: (pr_num = 7)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on orient_0817_7 t2_9  (cost=0.00..17.13 rows=3 width=40)"
"              Filter: (pr_num = 7)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on orient_0917_7 t2_10  (cost=0.00..17.13 rows=3 width=40)"
"              Filter: (pr_num = 7)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on orient_1017_7 t2_11  (cost=0.00..17.13 rows=3 width=40)"
"              Filter: (pr_num = 7)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on orient_1117_7 t2_12  (cost=0.00..17.13 rows=3 width=40)"
"              Filter: (pr_num = 7)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on orient_1217_7 t2_13  (cost=0.00..17.13 rows=3 width=40)"
"              Filter: (pr_num = 7)"
"  ->  Hash  (cost=70762.44..70762.44 rows=168815 width=61)"
"        ->  Append  (cost=0.00..70762.44 rows=168815 width=61)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on orient t1  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=40)"
"                    Filter: ((datetime >= '2017-04-04 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (datetime <= '2017-04-05 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (pr_num = 6))"
"              ->  Seq Scan on orient_6 t1_1  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=40)"
"                    Filter: ((datetime >= '2017-04-04 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (datetime <= '2017-04-05 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (pr_num = 6))"
"              ->  Index Scan using orient_0417_6_pkey on orient_0417_6 t1_2  (cost=0.43..70762.44 rows=168813 width=61)"
"                    Index Cond: ((datetime >= '2017-04-04 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (datetime <= '2017-04-05 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
"                    Filter: (pr_num = 6)"
```

Т.е в таком случае он сканирует все партиции по времени по второму прибору. Почему на основании условий `t1.datetime = t2.datetime` и `t1.datetime BETWEEN '2017-04-04 00:00:00' AND '2017-04-05 00:00:00'` планировщик не догадывается, что t2.datetime должен быть в том же диапазоне?

Comment: Потому что планировщики не такие умные, как нам хотелось бы.

Comment: @Mike мне просто казалось, что для планировщика такая задача должна быть тривиальной